# 310 Redirect a URL Containing a ? (question mark)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently in the final stages of redeveloping a website however having some trouble redirecting the old blog links to the new format.

We have inbound links to the old blog in the form of:

**Index Page**
http://www.domain_name.co.uk/blog-page/

Needs to become

http://www.domain_name.co.uk/news/

This is easy enough and has been done by using

```
RewriteRule ^blog-page$     /news/ [R=301,L]
```

**Profile page**
http://www.domain_name.co.uk/blog-page/index.php?/archives/1541-title-of-the-blog.html

The above needs to link to

http://www.domain_name.co.uk/news/1541-title-of-the-blog

However the '?' in the middle of the URL structure appears to break my rewriterule. I have read online about QUERYSTRING however I do not believe this solves my issue as there are no actual parameters passed through in the URL

The below code works but passes through the '/?/archives/' info also.

```
RewriteRule ^blog-page/index.php(.*)$   /news/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. There are several other sections of the previous site build which for some reason use the same URL structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an additional rule for matching query string. Have your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/archives/(.+?)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog-page/index\.php$ /news/%1? [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^blog-page$ /news/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: thank you very much. worked perfectly ! now just have to understand it myself :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. I have found http://askapache.com a a good resource for htaccess stuff